# Is there a method to create bl_info using variable?

Tags: python, add-on

I have noticed that when creating addon, if the `bl_info` is create with variable. The script will break the addon system. Causing disappear tab after restarting blender:

```
desc = 'Run script in any space with given name of script'
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "Run specified script in all context",
    "description": desc,  # Here, a variable. (And WTF is this code highlight?)
    "author": "hikariTW",
    "version": (0, 1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "TextEditor",
    "support": "TESTING",
    "category": "Interface",
}
```

[image]

Is there any workaround or this is normal when dealing with static examine of script when Blender try to list them out?

The test is done in Blender `2.83.4`

---

Further testing which also break addon:

- f-string and `str.format`
- formatting with const-like `15` `'foobar'` without variable.
- Conditional Expression: `"foo" if True else "bar"`

Comment: Have you tried `"description" : f"{desc}",` ?

Comment: Nope, any string format with any kind of variable even pure `int` or `str`. Including `f"{desc}"` and `"{}".format(150)`. It seems that it need to be pure text formatting without any statement.

Comment: Oh, alright. Are you dynamically pulling the description from another file / module or is it for a translation ?

Comment: Just simply want to separate code into different part for better formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

Sure this is a dupe, have searched and searched,

For want of a better reference

> **https://developer.blender.org/T53617**
>
> `bl_info` must be declared in the module.
>
> This is because `bl_info` is extracted without executing code.

*ie* the `bl_info` dictionary is grepped out of the addon module top level file (`foo.py` or `foo/__init__.py`) as a string where the  `locals` will not be available.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but shouldn't Blender handle the exception carefully and indicate that there is some invalid `bl_info` rather that just failed to fetch data and make whole addon panel failed?

Comment: Wish I could find when this was previously asked as IIRC it was well explained, on how the dictionaries are used to build the fake modules list. Yep could add some exception handling for this..... yet again the addons panel can  already be a ponderously slow beast.  Adding an exception test for something that as demonstrated  doesn't work, is fixed by not doing it.

Comment: .. have my nose in dynamically creating addons.  The concept of having a single tools umbrella addon has kinda taken a big  hit with the association of addons with workspaces, and currently end up with all or nothing. Might write a q re this one day.

Answer (score 3):

So it seems like Blender is using `ast.literal_eval()` for finding `bl_info` without execute whole addon content.

As the references said, using `eval` to evaluate arbitrary addon would be extremely dangerous. And the potential corrupt code will also make Blender vulnerable to malware.

#### Reference

- [literal_eval() — ast — Abstract Syntax Trees — Python 3.8.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
- [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)
- [Ned Batchelder: Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)